# Domain of convergence for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to check for which x this series is convergent: $x-x^4+x^9-{x^4}^2+{x^5}^2-...$

I found a general formula for this one: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}=(-1)^nx^{(n+1)^2}$

I have decided to use d'Alembert's ratio test.

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_{n+1} \over a_{n}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(-1)^{n+1}x^{(n+2)^2} \over (-1)^nx^{(n+1)^2}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-1)x^{2n+3}<1$

From this one, I could tell that the domain of convergence is for $x\ge0$. But according to Mathematica, it is for $x<1$. Did I make some mistake?

Comment: How are you concluding the domain of convergence is for $x\ge0$? And more simply observe convergence on $(-1,1)$ since it absolutely converges as a sub-series of the geometric series there, and fails to converge everywhere else by the term test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test, as you wrote it, is for series with positive terms. As it was mentioned in a comment above, what you can do is to apply the criteria to $\sum x^{2n+3}$ and conclude that the original series in absolutely convergent (and thus convergent) for $x \in (-1,1)$. For other values of $x$, $\lim (-1)^n x^{(n+1)^2} \ne 0$ and the series is divergent.

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely forgot that for altering series we do not use the ratio test.

Comment: @Camillus Wrong, you can still apply it. When it is conclusive though, it gives absolute convergence or divergence, and more specifically, the open interval of convergence, provided you compute the limit properly.